# Encoding JPEG images in a video while keeping the video playable at all times

Tags: video, jpeg, mjpeg

I have an application that fetches some JPEG images from an URL and I'd like to encode each of these images in a video, as they arrive.

The constraints are as follows:

- the video format should be as simple as possible so I can implement it quickly in C or there should exist a relatively non-bloated library that does this
- If the power fails at any point (or I forcefully close the application), the video should remain "viewable" and playable in a normal video player without requiring any other special handling regardless of how many (1 or n) JPEG images I added to it. In my mind this goes something like this: Starting with the first image onwards, I'd like the video to be "complete" and only append to it the following images in order to make a longer video.

I read about M-JPEG, but I'm not able to find any examples and or documentation on how to produce something like this by means of programming.

Again, the language will be C.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a simple header before each image,

```
--random-boundary-string
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: NNNNN
data...
--random-boundary-string
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: NNNNN
data...
```

Where `NNNNN` is the size of the Jpeg image, and `data...` is the full Jpeg image. Write to a file with `.mjpeg` extension. `mplayer` can play the resulting output, but I don't know how/if other players will handle it. Probably anything that uses libavcodec will handle it fine. You will have to use `mplayer -fps N` to play back at a reasonable speed.

I have a few projects that do this, and it works great.

Comment: For real-world sample data, see `http://www.mjpeg.net/` and pull some of the mjpeg streams with `wget`, then analyze with `strings` and `hexdump -Cv`.